# CSS floating and clearing paragraph

Tags: css, css-float

I have this layout [issue](http://jsfiddle.net/grJ7k/) - I don't want the **date paragraph** stick to the space under the image, but under the **abstract paragraph** instead. The space under the **image paragraph** should be kept clear - nothing goes under it.

I tried to use `clear:left` on the **image paragraph** but it won't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the `margin-left`. Here is a working sample: [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/WhAdN/1/)

Also, you have `div#side` in the class definition for the date paragraph that will keep jsfiddle from recognizing the styles.

Edit: Sorry, posted the wrong link.

Comment: thanks. I think prefer using `margin-left` than float the paragraph... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/nZvum/

Comment: Thanks George. I thought of that. But is it possible to avoid using `div` in `li`?

Comment: Don't think so, you have to contain all the elements you want on the right hand side

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you had `div#side`, which wasn't anywhere in there, so your date element wasn't responding to the CSS.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grJ7k/5/)

Comment: The float to the right makes the columns not line up properly. You would have to define a margin-right to make them line up, in addition to the float.